# how to create and modify multiple dynamic textareas in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am creating a backbone.js app with consecutive text areas for individual instructions to be entered consecutively. At the end of each instruction, a button is pushed that spawns the next textarea. I am wondering if there is a way to add dynamic text to the beginning of each text box such as step 1, step  2, .... dynamically so that I can add drag and drop later so that steps are listed consecutively.

thanks

```
<script type="text/template" id="direction-control-template">

    <table class="tblDirections">
        <tr>
            <td class="Directionlabel">Step : </td>
            <td class="Direction"><textarea rows="5" cols="70">Step # :</textarea><br></td>
            <td>
                    <button type="button" id="btnAddDirection" class="btn btn-success btn-xs addIngredient">+</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr />
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, I was moving things around a lot due to recommendations and attempts using online sources. I should have tidied up the code prior to posting.

Comment: Kyle's answer seems like a good start. You might want to chop your template into a couple pieces to make it easier to add new `<textarea>`s though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add property to your view that `increments` each time you click the add `button`.

```
Backbone.View.extend({
    directionCount: 0,

    events: {
        'click #btnAddDirection': 'addDirection'
    },

    addDirection: function()
    {
        // Each time the #btnAddDirection is clicked the views directionCount
        // property is incremented, you can then pass this value to your
        // textarea template to display the count.
        this.directionCount++;
    }
});
```

Check out this [**live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/kq3mz/1/).

Comment: Thanks, Kyle. That was most of what I needed